# Couldn't expose PostgreSQL to cloud via Google Virtual Machine (through reverse SSH)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, ssh-tunnel

I would like to expose the Postgresql running in my RPi to the cloud, using Google Virtual Machine (through reverse ssh tunnelling). But I couldn't achieve though.

***The following are the steps done in Google Virtual Machine.***

1. Added the firewall rule with tag-name as `allow-postgresql` [image]
2. Added the tag name `allow-postgresql` to Network tags of the VM Instance [image]
3. Restarted the machine

***The following are the steps done in RPi***

1. Installed PostgreSQL. Up and Running.
2. Generate SSH keys.
3. Add the public key to Google Virtual Machine -> SSH Key list.
4. Executed the following command
   ssh -f -N -R 5432:localhost:5432 $google_vm_ip

***The following are the tests made in RPi***

1. nc -zv localhost 5432

- Which produces the output `Connection to localhost 5432 port [tcp/postgresql] succeeded!`

***The following are the tests made in Google Virtual Machine (in SSH)***

1. nc -zv localhost 5432

- Which produces the output `Connection to localhost 5432 port [tcp/postgresql] succeeded!`

2. nc -zv domain.com 5432

- Which produces the output `nc: connect to domain.com port 5432 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`

3. nc -zv <public_ip_of_vm> 5432

- Which producec the output `nc: connect to <public_ip_of_vm> port 5432 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`

So, If I enter via SSH, then I am able to access the reverse SSH tunnel. But for some reason, I cannot access it publicly.

**Update**
The following are the test made

| Command executed in RPi | Command executed in Google VM | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No tunnel | nc -zv localhost 5432 | nc: connect to localhost 5432 port (tcp) failed: Connection refused |
| ssh -N -R 5432:localhost:5432 <remote_public_ip> | nc -zv localhost 5432 | nc: connection to localhost port 5432 (tcp) succeeded! |
|  | nc -zv <remote_private_ip> 5432 | nc: connect to <remote_private_ip> 5432 port (tcp) failed: Connection refused |
|  | nc -zv <remote_public_ip> 5432 | nc: connect to <remote_public_ip> 5432 port (tcp) failed: Connection refused |
| ssh -N -R 5432:<remote_private_ip>:5432 <remote_public_ip> | nc -zv localhost 5432 | nc: connection to localhost port 5432 (tcp) succeeded! |
|  | nc -zv <remote_private_ip> 5432 | nc: connect to <remote_private_ip> 5432 port (tcp) failed: Connection refused |
|  | nc -zv <remote_public_ip> 5432 | nc: connect to <remote_public_ip> 5432 port (tcp) failed: Connection refused |

*I am not sure, what I am missing. Any ideas would be helpful.*

Comment: I posted an answer however, I would not open port 5432 to the world. You will be under attack very quickly. Make sure that you understand this and how to secure PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, But this is a kind of experiment only.

Comment: If you want to let the entire world access your PostgreSQL, why don't you just do that?  What is the point of trying to set up a fake tunnel which provides no security?

Comment: You need the 4 argument form of -R, not the 3 argument form.  You also need additional configuration of the sshd.  See the manual for -R of `ssh`.  But this is not a programming question, it is network question, so it probably better for superuser (maybe?) than stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi @jjanes,  as I told earlier, this is an experiment on learning tunnel. I was able to do the similar configuration in local network, but couldn't achieve the same using Google virtual machine. And for your second comment, I see similar questions were posted here, so I posted here as well.